# Supervisor+nginx: не работает tail -f

Tags: nginx, supervisord

Есть `supervisord` на порту 9001. Организован доступ к его веб-интерфейсу через nginx примерно так:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name supervisor.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_read_timeout 120s;
  }
}
```

В веб-интерфейсе Supervisor есть функция `tail -f`, позволяющая следить за логами в реальном времени.

Если открывать `tail -f` напрямую у Supervisor по ссылке вида `http://example.com:9001/logtail/service_name`, то всё отлично работает. <sup><sub>*(На настоящем продакшене порт 9001, естественно, недоступен из интернета ради безопасности)*</sub></sup>

Однако то же самое, но через nginx: `https://supervisor.example.com/logtail/service_name` — уже не работает: в браузере отображается пустая страница с бесконечной загрузкой.

Кто виноват и что делать?

Comment: ассоциация: https://serverfault.com/questions/568317/supervisord-inet-http-server-behind-nginx

Comment: (если ассоциации на serverfault вообще работают)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, проксирующий nginx занимается кэшированием ответа сервера: он сперва пытается дождаться полного тела ответа и только после этого начинает отправлять ответ клиенту. Естественно, для `tail -f` nginx не дождётся полного тела ответа никогда (ну или отвалится по таймауту), поэтому буферизацию нужно отключить:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

Во-вторых, для обновления лога в реальном времени Supervisor использует `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, который доступен только в HTTP/1.1, в то время как nginx по умолчанию использует HTTP/1.0, так что нужно ещё сменить версию протокола:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

В-третьих, по невыясненным мной причинам (возможно, это баг?) Supervisor отказывается отдавать ответ, если указан HTTP-заголовок `Connection`, поэтому его придётся убирать:

```
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

В целом конфиг получается такой:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name supervisor.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_read_timeout 120s;
  }
}
```

После его применения `tail -f` заработает.